# find the maximum number of courses i can participate in

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find an optimal (in means of complexity) algo to get the maximum number of courses i can participate in. I don't care about the total length of the courses nor the courses itself. It's all about being present at as many courses as possible.

Given are two arrays S and E. S[i] contains the starting time of the course, E[i] contains the corresponding ending time. Arrays are already sorted by E. Since I'm not The Flash I can't join a course where the ending time of the first equals the starting time of the following.

Here's an example:

```
S = [
    "2014-11-06 01:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 03:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 07:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 09:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 09:00:00"
]

E = [
    "2014-11-06 05:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 06:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 08:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 09:00:00",
    "2014-11-06 10:00:00"
]
```

For those values the correct answer would be 3 since I can participate in course 1, 3 and 5 (other combinations are possible too)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Second last elements are same for both

Comment: Do you have to sit each course in full? Or you can just be present a little, then move to another one?

Comment: I've to be present until the end of the course

Comment: I think that the problem is NP-Complete, you will have to pass throw all solutions to find the best one. Try to do your best to not try solutions that you already know that are impossible (subset impossible)

Comment: Your problem is similar than the Maximum coverage problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem).
The Greedy algorithm seems to be is essentially the best-possible polynomial time approximation algorithm for maximum coverage.

Comment: @Gabz: Really?  Maybe I misunderstood, because to my eye this appears to be a trivial dynamic-programming thing.  It's like... a textbook example.  O(N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Core Idea

The idea is to use a recursion to check all of the courses. The basic solution is explained in Timothy Ha's answer. For the sake of clarity, I recall it :

1. Sort courses by S
2. Begin at S<sub>1</sub> :
3. Find *k* = min(*j, E<sub>1</sub> < S<sub>j</sub>*). If it exists, find the best fit for *S<sub>k</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>*
4. If *k* > 2 (= current course + 1), find the best fit for *S<sub>2</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>*
5. Return the best fit between Step 3 and Step 4.

### Time optimization with dynamic programming

But you could optimize it by storing the intermediate values. To do so, instead of starting the recursion from the beginning, we will start from the end !

Let *b* be an array of *n* integers initialized to 0. Let *b<sub>n</sub>* = 1. Finally, let *i = n-1*

While *i* > 0, perform the following :

1. Consider we take the course *i*. We must find *k* = min(*j, E<sub>i</sub> < S<sub>j</sub>*). If such a *k* exists, it enforces *i+1 ≤ k*.
2. If *k* exists, then *b<sub>i</sub>* = max(1 + *b<sub>k</sub>, b<sub>i+1</sub>*).
3. Otherwise, *b<sub>i</sub> = b<sub>i+1</sub>* (We don't have to explicitly state "max(1, *b<sub>i+1</sub>*)", since 1 ≤ *b<sub>i+1</sub>* )
4. Decrement *i* and proceed to Step 1.

When the loop is over, the solution is *b<sub>1</sub>*.

Here is the solution in a C fashion

```c
// I suppose S[] is sorted by increasing order
// E[] are the end times associated with S :
// (the course that starts at S[i] ends at E[i]
int findBestNumber(ADateType S[], ADateType E[], int n) {
    int i = n-1, k, res;
    int *sol = NULL;
    if(!(sol = malloc(n*sizeof (int))))
        return -1;
    memset(sol, 0, sizeof (*sol));
    sol[n-1] = 1;
    while(i-- > 0) {
        k = findMinIndex(E[i], S);
        if(k >= 0) // k exists
            sol[i] = max(1 + sol[k], sol[i+1]);
        else // k does not exist, we return a value like -1
            sol[i] = sol[i+1];
    }
    res = sol[0];
    free(sol);
    return res;
}
```

`findMinIndex(after, S)` search the minimum index *k* such that *after* ≤ *S<sub>k</sub>*. Since `S` is sorted when this function is called, it is a simple binary search. In the above, I supposed we returned a negative value from `findMinIndex()` if we could not find such an index.

### Space and Time Complexity for the *DP* version

In the *Dynamic Programming* version, we just compute step by step the intermediate results and we do so only once. Thus, this is O(n). The Space complexity is also O(n) since we need to store n intermediate values.

But remember we had to sort the courses by starting time ! This operation, using an appropriate sorting algorithm (eg. *merge sort*), is O(n. log(n)). The final time complexity is thus O(n. log(n)).

### Bonus : A working C implementation

[On Ideone](http://ideone.com/cPQl0a)

*Note :* After reading the question again, I noticed I can't select courses that starts at the same time than the ending time of the previously taken course ... To exclude these, just turn the `>=`s in `findMinIndex()` into `>`s

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning of dynamic programming.  Turns out there is a whole article at Wikipedia which lists "Algorithms that use dynamic programming", including "Interval scheduling" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling and the proposed algorithm is similar to one named as "Greedy polynomial solution" there.  O(N log N) because this includes sorting.

Comment: Good solution! But don't forget that this Greedy Algorithm doesn't give you the best solution in every cases. So, if n is small, it could be better to through all the posibilities!

Comment: @Gabz It goes through any possibility : the loop finds at each iteration the best solution for a subset [_i, n_] by considering if course _i_ must be taken or not. It does  so using the already computed intermediate solutions which also considered the same choice for the subsets [_k, n_], with _k_ > _i_ ... In the end, we took every possible choice into balance.

Comment: @Retiro : My fault, I didn't understand well the problem and thought it was an Group Interval Scheduling Maximization!

Comment: @Rerito thank you very much.. bonus question: how to sort both arrays in the same way? at the moment both arrays are sorted for E not for S :)

Comment: @DanielFreudenberger The best idea is to gather the starting time and the ending time of a course in a structure and sort these structures according to the starting time. This way the ending times stay put with the related starting times :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that each course needs to be participated in full, I think algorithm can be like this:

1. sort courses by S
2. If you join S<sub>1</sub>, find list of courses with S > E<sub>1</sub>; if that list starts with S<sub>k</sub>, then use recursion for (S<sub>k</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>), total result will be (result from recursion) + 1.
3. If you skip S<sub>1</sub>, use recursion for (S<sub>2</sub>, S<sub>3</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>) and the value that comes from it.
4. Choose maximum of values coming from steps 2 and 3.

UPD (from comments)  We should check more than just at first step, or recursion should store results for [K-N] sets, so as not to calculate again. I can imagine a case like this: `S1, S2, E1, E2, S3, E3, .... SN, EN` The part [3-N] can be calculated twice in recursion (with or without S1) if we don't check

Comment: the question might be stupid but how do I decide if I join S1?

Comment: There are two choices at first step: to join S1 or not. You calculate till the end using recursion, and if result with S1 is bigger, you join it :-)

I also thought of complexity, since it is a linear scan (two in parallel) down the queue of courses, it should be O(N).

Comment: Daniel, you will translate this to code if the idea is correct, right?

Comment: of course I will. Still thinking about the complexity and that there should be a way to reduce the complexity to something less complex than O(N)

Comment: @DanielFreudenberger, How can you reach a complexity under O(n) ?! You have to process every course to make a decision right ?

Comment: Oh, and you have to perform the dichotomy at every step, so it's more like O(2^n)

Comment: @Rerito - I think it's not as bad as O(2^n). We just need to check if S(k) is same as S(2) or not.  Worst case for this kind of going down the queue is when all courses are separate and we are doing double work at each step if we don't check.  If courses overlap, the recursion will be faster.

Comment: In average, I agree, but suppose you can engage every course, you'll end up performing the dichotomy at each course. Of course, you can reduce the time complexity using dynamic programming :)

Comment: @DanielFreudenberger

We should check more than just at first step, or recursion should store results for [K-N] sets, so as not to calculate again.  I can imagine a case like this:  `S1, S2, E1, E2, S3, E3, .... SN, EN`  The part [3-N] can be calculated twice in recursion (with or without S1) if we don't check.